# Showed text in a NSComboBox with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm adding an object to a ComboBox using this code :

```
Ploofed *uped = [Ploofed initwithImageAndURL:(NSImage *)myImage :(NSString *)returnString];
[_OldTrans addItemWithObjectValue:(id)uped];
[_OldTrans selectItemWithObjectValue:(id)uped];
```

But there is only a blank line in the ComboBox List, how do I set the text of the added object ?

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's docs on combo boxes (Introduction to Combo Boxes):

When you set or retrieve a combo box’s value with the standard NSControl methods (such as setStringValue:, stringValue, setFloatValue:, and floatValue), you’re setting or retrieving the value of the combo box’s text field, and not the current selection of the list. Programmatically changing the combo box’s value does not change what’s selected in the combo box’s list. Conversely, programmatically changing what’s selected in the list does not change the text field’s value. If you want the text field value and the list selection to match up, you need to set them individually.

For example, say you want to initialize the combo box’s list and text field to the list’s third item. This code does that for a combo box that maintains an internal item list:

```
[myComboBox selectItemAtIndex:2]; // First item is at index 0
[myComboBox setObjectValue:[myComboBox objectValueOfSelectedItem]];
```

Comment: FWIW I just tried `selectItemAtIndex` and observed that it actually changes the text.